# Using different Hystrix command name for metrics

Tags: hystrix

I am working on a system where Hystrix commands are created dynamically. There is only a single implementation of `HystrixCommand` which receives its configuration as well as the code (`Callable`) to be executed inside `run` method.

Commands calling the same remote service have different command keys based on the component they are executed in so their circuit breakers are independent on each other. However, I would like to have them aggregated in the metrics stream under a single name depending on the remote service being called. Is that possible?

I can see there is a [command group](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#CommandGroup) property and I set it to my remote service name but it seems that Hystrix Dashboard groups the entries together based on a [command name](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#CommandName).

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this provide the behaviour that you are looking for?

```java
public class NamedHystrixCommand extends HystrixCommand<Object> {

    private static final HystrixCommandGroupKey GROUP_KEY =
        HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("Host Routing");
    private static final HystrixThreadPoolProperties.Setter THREAD_POOL_PROPERTIES =
        HystrixThreadPoolProperties.Setter()
                .withMaximumSize(100);
    private static final HystrixCommandProperties.Setter COMMAND_PROPERTIES =
        HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
                .withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds(5000)
                .withMetricsHealthSnapshotIntervalInMilliseconds(1000);

    private final Callable<Object> callable;

    public NamedHystrixCommand(
        String metricName,
        Callable<Object> callable) {
        super(HystrixCommand.Setter
            .withGroupKey(GROUP_KEY)
            .andThreadPoolPropertiesDefaults(THREAD_POOL_PROPERTIES)
            .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(COMMAND_PROPERTIES)
            .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(metricName)));
        this.callable = callable;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object run() throws Exception {
        return callable.call();
    }
}
```